Powershell command query with where-object
I run command: netstat -aon | where-object {$_.State -eq "LISTENING"}. It does not return any results. But if I run netstat -aon | where-object {$_.State -eq "*"} - returns all results  including "LISTENING". Any idea what is wrong with the first cmdlet example?

Are you sure you're using -eq and not -like?

netstat isn't powershell.  Try Get-NetTCPConnection

See: Get foreign address name using NETSTAT for established active TCP connections and Is there a way to convert tables of text into a PowerShell Object

netstat returns a string array, not a object with properties.

thanks! how do you know it returns a string array? or shall I ask what is the way to figure this out if you could share some info would appreciate

You can use the .GetType() method with any variable in powershell, which returns what kind of object it is. I simply wrote $varname=netstat -aon; $a.gettype().
